# Is it possible to use AnimateWindow with AW_BLEND when using a layered window?

Tags: winapi, graphics, gdi

I am displaying a window using `UpdateLayeredWindow` and would like to add transition animations. `AnimateWindow` works if I use the slide or roll effects (though there is some flickering). However, when I try to use `AW_BLEND` to produce a fade effect, I not only lose any translucency after the animation (per-pixel and on the entire image), but a default window border also appears. Is there a way to prevent the border from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm using `UpdateLayeredWindow`, `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` will not work. The diagram [here](http://alexkr.com/source-code/50/layered-windows-and-updatelayeredwindow/) was pretty useful. Instead, I just need to call `UpdateLayeredWindow` in a loop while decreasing the `SourceConstantAlpha` member of the `BLENDFUNCTION` structure. In fact, the pointer to the `BLENDFUNCTION` structure, the handle to the layered window, and the flags are the only things I needed to pass into `UpdateLayeredWindow` if the alpha is all that is changing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to successfully fade up/down a window (without the complications you're describing) is by first creating a window with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended style.  I then start a timer (30ms) that gradually fades the window by calling something like:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(0, 
                          (BYTE)(m_nAnimationCount * WINDOW_ALPHA), 
                          LWA_ALPHA);
```

where `WINDOW_ALPHA` is 23 (seems to look the best), and `m_nAnimationCount` is a count from 0 to 10 (or 10 to 0 if fading down).

If you discover a better way of doing this, I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: UpdateLayeredWindow and SetLayeredWindowAttributes don't really get along :-\